# How can you format the result of a formula as s number

Tags: excel-2007, cell-formatting

I'm using a formula in Excel 2007 to grab a mailbox size from a string. I'm stripping out all of the text before and after, and removing the `,` characters, yet Excel will not format the result as a number.

Because of this, I can't run any statistics such as total size or average size.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(MailboxEX01[[#This Row],[TotalItemSize]], FIND("(", MailboxEX01[[#This Row],[TotalItemSize]]) + 1, FIND("bytes", MailboxEX01[[#This Row],[TotalItemSize]]) - (FIND("(", MailboxEX01[[#This Row],[TotalItemSize]]) + 2)), ",", "")
```

I tried `=TEXT({the above}, "#,##0")`, which successfully added the `,` character as the thousands separator, but (I guess unsurprisingly) still failed to format the cell as a number.

Does anybody know how I can force the result in this cell to format as a number? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula takes text values, strips stuff out, and replaces stuff. But the result is still text. If the result of that formula contains only the characters 0 to 9, you can coerce it into a number by using

```
={your formula}+0
```

or

```
={your formula}*1
```

or

```
=--({your formula})
```

Using `=TEXT({your formula}, "format")` will not produce a number. The `TEXT()` function returns text, as the name implies.

But if you use a mathematical operator on a number that is stored as text (or a text that represents a number), the maths operation will coerce that text value into a real number. The third suggestion uses the double unary (Google that) to coerce the text into a number.